# PHP Modulo and pow()

Tags: php, double, modulus, pow

Can this be made robust? at various points I'm finding that `5 % 2 = 0`
and I've never encountered this 'quirk' before, and probably due to ignorance around precision :/

```
$checkPrimeCubeRoots = array(125, 124);

foreach ($checkPrimeCubeRoots as $int)
{
    $cubeRoot = pow($int, 1/3); // double
    // $int = 125, gives $cubeRoot = 5
    // $int = 124, gives $cubeRoot = 4.986....

    // some code that check for prime, but let's just check if divisble by 2

    echo $cubeRoot % 2;            // 0 -> yup 5 is divisible by 2
    echo intval($cubeRoot) % 2;    // 0 -> yup

    // try round -> but gives false positive for 124
    echo round ($cubeRoot) %2;     // 1 -> nope, but in both cases :/   
}
```

Comment: If you add in `echo intval($cubeRoot).PHP_EOL;` you will see how binary representation of numbers can be imprecise at times.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is intended to be used with integers only. The result of using it on floating point numbers does is somewhat unpredictable. And even though the result of `pow(125, 1/3)` might seem an integer, it's being stored internally as a floating point (there is an interesting [article](https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html) by *NikiC* if you want to know more about the internals).

One quick solution is to use [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) instead, which is the floating point version.

```
echo fmod(pow(125, 1/3), 2); # 1
echo fmod(pow(124, 1/3), 2); # 0.98663095223865
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with any float/double type values, there is a possibility that some slight difference in the internal representation and the actual value are stored. Also you can use `fmod()` which works with floating point numbers better...

```
$checkPrimeCubeRoots = array(125, 124);

foreach ($checkPrimeCubeRoots as $int)
{
    $cubeRoot = pow($int, 1/3); // double
    // $int = 125, gives $cubeRoot = 5
    // $int = 124, gives $cubeRoot = 4.986....

    // some code that check for prime, but let's just check if divisble by 2

    echo "%=".$cubeRoot % 2 .PHP_EOL;;            // 0 -> yup 5 is divisible by 2
    echo "intval=".intval($cubeRoot) % 2 .PHP_EOL;;    // 0 -> yup
    echo "fmod()=".fmod($cubeRoot,2).PHP_EOL;
    // try round -> but gives false positive for 124
    echo round ($cubeRoot) %2 .PHP_EOL;     // 1 -> nope, but in both cases :/
}
```

Which gives...

```
%=0
intval=0
fmod()=1
1
%=0
intval=0
fmod()=0.98663095223865
1
```